# How can I exchange files between the virtual and physical drive in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8-preview

I've set up a VirtualBox running the Windows 8 Developer Preview.

Windows 8 is running well even inside VirtualBox but somehow it doesn't support the guest service needed to exchange files between the virtual and the physical drive.

Is there some other way to do this? The file is ~8GB so uploading would take days.

Comment: What is your host OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 supports a good old fashion File share.  Then you can just copy the file via SMB.